# How many numeric outliers with 'hundred' can be used?

Tags: numbers

In English there are numeric outliers from ten hundred to twenty-nine hundred. I googled and found a song with the words 'forty-five hundred times'.

Is it only a made-up word for the song or there are really such words as, for example, eighty-three hundred, thirty-seven hundred? If there are, how many of them?

Comment: You're perfectly entitled to say "forty-seven point two hundred times" (even though it might draw strange looks).  You're simply specifying a number of hundreds.  Idiomatically, anything from "one hundred time" to "ninety-nine hundred times" is perfectly acceptable.  Over that and you generally should shift into thousands, or spell out the exact number.

Comment: What do you mean "numeric outliers"? This is perfectly normal for all numbers because it is more succinct than using both thousands and hundreds. That's just wasted breath. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, in conversational and written English one can use multiples of one hundred up to ninety-nine hundred. In written English there are common stylistic practices that will usually turn the larger values into digits. However, one common style is to never begin a sentence with a number as digits. This style will often result in larger numbers being spelled out. "Sixteen hundred and eighty soldiers were fielded by..." Numbers below ten are often spelled out in writing, with higher values being expressed in digits, making high multiples of one hundred rather uncommon as words.

Answer (score -1):

There are eighty one words for hundreds that are more than nine hundred but less than ten thousand.

They are:

"Eleven Hundred
"

"Twelve Hundred
"

"Thirteen Hundred
"

"Fourteen Hundred
"

"Fifteen Hundred
"

"Sixteen Hundred
"

"Seventeen Hundred
"

"Eighteen Hundred
"

"Nineteen Hundred
"

"Twenty One Hundred
"

"Twenty Two Hundred
"

"Twenty Three Hundred
"

"Twenty Four Hundred
"

"Twenty Five Hundred
"

"Twenty Six Hundred
"

"Twenty Seven Hundred
"

"Twenty Eight Hundred
"

"Twenty Nine Hundred
"

"Thirty One Hundred
"

"Thirty Two Hundred
"

"Thirty Three Hundred
"

"Thirty Four Hundred
"

"Thirty Five Hundred
"

"Thirty Six Hundred
"

"Thirty Seven Hundred
"

"Thirty Eight Hundred
"

"Thirty Nine Hundred
"

"Forty One Hundred
"

"Forty Two Hundred
"

"Forty Three Hundred
"

"Forty Four Hundred
"

"Forty Five Hundred
"

"Forty Six Hundred
"

"Forty Seven Hundred
"

"Forty Eight Hundred
"

"Forty Nine Hundred
"

"Fifty One Hundred
"

"Fifty Two Hundred
"

"Fifty Three Hundred
"

"Fifty Four Hundred
"

"Fifty Five Hundred
"

"Fifty Six Hundred
"

"Fifty Seven Hundred
"

"Fifty Eight Hundred
"

"Fifty Nine Hundred
"

"Sixty One Hundred
"

"Sixty Two Hundred
"

"Sixty Three Hundred
"

"Sixty Four Hundred
"

"Sixty Five Hundred
"

"Sixty Six Hundred
"

"Sixty Seven Hundred
"

"Sixty Eight Hundred
"

"Sixty Nine Hundred
"

"Seventy One Hundred
"

"Seventy Two Hundred
"

"Seventy Three Hundred
"

"Seventy Four Hundred
"

"Seventy Five Hundred
"

"Seventy Six Hundred
"

"Seventy Seven Hundred
"

"Seventy Eight Hundred
"

"Seventy Nine Hundred
"

"Eighty One Hundred
"

"Eighty Two Hundred
"

"Eighty Three Hundred
"

"Eighty Four Hundred
"

"Eighty Five Hundred
"

"Eighty Six Hundred
"

"Eighty Seven Hundred
"

"Eighty Eight Hundred
"

"Eighty Nine Hundred
"

"Ninety One Hundred
"

"Ninety Two Hundred
"

"Ninety Three Hundred
"

"Ninety Four Hundred
"

"Ninety Five Hundred
"

"Ninety Six Hundred
"

"Ninety Seven Hundred
"

"Ninety Eight Hundred
"

"Ninety Nine Hundred
"